# Sort by month expressed by a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following sorting problem in SQL.

```
SELECT time, orderValue
FROM orders
ORDER BY time
```

The issue is that time is expressed by a string in the following format:

```
May 2012

June 2012

...

June 2013
```

The ORDER BY clause however sorts the problem in an alphabetic order (which is not strange since it's defined as a string). How to sort this in a correct order based on year and month?

Comment: Best way would be to not store it like that. e.g. use `datetime` datatype and store as `1 May 2012` instead. Or have `month`,`year` numeric columns.

Comment: Is `time` always in the format `<fullname_of_month> YYYY`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT time, orderValue
FROM orders
ORDER BY CONVERT (DATETIME, '01 ' + time, 104)
```

Comment: Really smart, I didn't realize that you could use convert in a flexible way like this. Thanks!